# Symfony2/ Use custom repository method in a formType

Tags: symfony, repository

I am new with Symfony2, hopefully I am clear enough.

I have a repository:

```
class districtRepository extends EntityRepository
{
     public function findAllFromCity($idCity)
    {


            return $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
                        ->where('d.city = :city')
                        ->setParameter('city', $idCity)
                        ->orderBy('d.name', 'ASC');
                        ->getQuery()
                        ->getResult();

    }
}
```

And a form type

```
class searchPropertyType extends AbstractType
{

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        // return array('validation_constraint' => $collectionConstraint
       return array ('required'=>false, 'csrf_protection' => true); 
    }


    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        $builder
            ->add('keywords')
            ->add('disctrict')    
            ->add('price_min')
            ->add('price_max')
            ->add('type')                                             
            ->add('date_from' , 'date', array('widget' => 'single_text'))
            ->add('date_to' , 'date', array('widget' => 'single_text'))
        ;


    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'searchProperty';
    }
}
```

How do I simply use `findAllFromCity()` to get a list of option in `->add('disctrict')` ??

I know the Query Builder solution, but it makes me repeating my code.

I've read about the service container solution. Is is applicabe in my case? Can you show me how or put me on good tracks??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony2 choice field not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16463926/symfony2-choice-field-not-working)

Answer (score 4):

1. Indeed, only way to access your 'findAllFromCity' method in the 'searchPropertyType' class is to inject the Doctrine registry.

   In your form type class:

   ```
   use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;

   class searchPropertyType extends AbstractType
   {
       private $doctrine;

       public function __construct(RegistryInterface $doctrine)
       {
           $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
       }
   ```

   In your services.xml file:

   ```
   <service id="my_project.form.type.search_property" class="{mynamespace}\searchPropertyType" public="false">
       <tag name="form.type" />
       <argument type="service" id="doctrine" />
   </service>
   ```
2. In order to use this this method, you'll have to use the 'choice' type with 'choices' or 'choice_list' option.

   In your form type class:

   ```
   public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
   {
       $builder
           // ...
           ->add('disctrict', 'choice', $this->getDistrictChoices($options['city_id']))
           // ...
       ;
   }

   private function getDistrictChoices()
   {
       $choices = array();
       $districts = $this->doctrine->getRepository('MyBundle:District')->findAllFromCity($cityId);

       foreach ($dictricts as $dictrict) {
           $choices[$district->getId()] = $district->getName();
       }

       return $choices;
   }
   ```

Of course, this is an example and it needs to be adapted.
And remember: class name fisrt letters are always in upper case.

Comment: Hi Simon, many thanks for the answer and your time. Much appreciate!!!! I have no time today to test it, but I get back to it tomorow. It is very very clear now anyway. Thanks again

Comment: Hi SImon, I have updated a new response with some updates.
It works, but it is still very confusing. Am I actually using service here? Because if I remove the service.yml it i still working!!
Instead of 
$districts = $this->doctrine->getRepository('FlatShanghaidefaultBundle:district')->findByDefaultCity();
shouldn' I use something like
$this->get('search_property') ???

I ask because really it is still so confusing for me.
I really appreciate your help ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Simon, I have updated as follow and it is now working!

**searchController:**

```
public function basicsearchAction(Request $request)
{   
    $form = $this->createForm(new searchPropertyType($this->getDoctrine()));

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $form->bindRequest($request);

}
```

**searchPropertyType**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('keywords')
            ->add('district', 'choice', array('choices'=>$this->getDistrictChoices(), 'multiple'=>true) )     
            ->add('price_min')
            ->add('price_max')
            ->add('type', 'entity', array('class'=>'FlatShanghaidefaultBundle:propertytype', 
                                          'property'=>'name', 
                                          'multiple'=>true              

                ))


            ->add('date_from' , 'date', array('widget' => 'single_text'))
            ->add('date_to' , 'date', array('widget' => 'single_text'))
        ;


    }

    private function getDistrictChoices()
{
    $choices = array();
    $districts = $this->doctrine->getRepository('FlatShanghaidefaultBundle:district')->findByDefaultCity();

    foreach ($districts as $district) {
        $choices[$district->getId()] = $district->getName();
    }


    return $choices;
}
```

**service.yml**

```
services:
    search_property:
        class:        FlatShanghai\propertyBundle\Form\searchPropertyType
        arguments:    [doctrine]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also concerned about repeated code.  Not only for my query builder, but also didn't want to write a custom choice mapping such as "getDistrictChoices".  I chose to abstract my query inside my EntityRepository to make it available in my form type as well.

Here's what I did.

My form:

```
class UserEditType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @var Session $session
     */
    private $session;

    public function __construct(Session $session){
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('firstName')
            ->add('middleName')
            ->add('lastName')
            ->add('username')
            ->add('userStatus', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => UserStatus::class,
                'property' => 'status',
                'query_builder' => function(UserStatusRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                        ->orderBy('s.status');
                },
            ])
            ->add('agency', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => WorkflowGroup::class,
                'property' => 'groupName',
                'query_builder' => function(WorkflowGroupRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createSelectAllQB($this->session->get(AbstractController::SESSION_KEY_AGENCY_ID));
                },
            ])
            ->add('phoneNumber')
            ->add('email', EmailType::class)
            ->add('activationDate', DateType::class, [
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'format' => 'M/d/yyyy',
                'attr' => [
                    'data-provide' => 'datepicker',
                    'data-date-format' => 'mm/dd/yyyy',
                    'data-date-show-on-focus' => 'false',
                    'data-date-auto-format' => 'true'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('expirationDate', DateTimeType::class, [ 'widget' => 'single_text', 'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm' ]);
        ;
    }
...
}
```

My Repository:

```
class WorkflowGroupRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function createSelectAllQB($agencyId)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('w')
            ->addOrderBy('w.groupName', 'ASC')
            ->andWhere('w.agencyId = :agencyId')
            ->setParameter('agencyId', $agencyId);
    }

    public function selectAll($agencyId)
    {
        return $this->createSelectAllQB($agencyId)->getQuery()->execute();
    }
}
```